# Input type no se agranda

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo un sitio web para dominar mejor HTML y CSS pero tengo un problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que el Input (El recuadro de Escribe tu direccion), solo lo puedo agrandar lateralmente usando px pero este es un problema si cambia la resolucion, si intento hacerlo con 90%, no se ocupa todo.

```css
.box{

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background: #9b9b9b;
  height: 100px;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;

}


.box .maps .direccion{

  width: 90%;
  height: 20px;

}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="maps">
        <input type="text" name="direction" placeholder="Escribe tu direccion" class="direccion">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten en cuenta lo siguiente:

> Un elemento `inline` NO será afectado por propiedades como `width` o `height`

Y elementos como `<input>`, `<button>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`; tienen un `display:inline` por defecto

Para solucionarlo, nos han traído una opción mejor: `inline-block`

La cual hace que se combine con `inline` y `block` a la vez, como es `block` también, el elemento si se verá afectado por `width` y `height`

```css
.box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background: #9b9b9b;
  height: 100px;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.maps {
  width: 100%;
}

.direccion {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="maps">
        <input type="text" name="direction" placeholder="Escribe tu direccion" class="direccion">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Entonces esto se puede aplicar para cualquier tipo de input?

Comment: @rapac56 Si....

Answer (score 0):

Para mantener el código que ya tienes, solo te diría que realices los siguientes cambios:

- No necesitas un [selector de combinador de descendientes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), basta con aplicarle el ancho al elemento deseado y ya<sup>1</sup>

  ```
  .direccion{
      width: 90%;
  }
  ```
- Si lo que buscas es con *flexbox* centrar vertical y horizontalmente el input entonces lo estas haciendo mal, debería ser a la clase `maps` a la que se le deben asignar esas propiedades y valores así:

  ```
  .maps{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 5px solid black;
    background: #9b9b9b;
    height: 100px;
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  ```

Con este resultado:

```html
    <style>
    .maps{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      border: 5px solid black;
      background: #9b9b9b;
      height: 100px;
      width: 40%;
      margin: auto;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    
    .direccion{
      width: 90%;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="maps">
            <input type="text" name="direction" placeholder="Escribe tu direccion" class="direccion">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Notas importantes**

- <sup>1</sup> Es muy importante que tengas en cuenta lo que el otro usuario te menciona respecto a la naturaleza *inline* o *block* de los elementos como en este caso el `input`, pero aqui en particular y aclarando que esta respuesta no se basa en dicho enlace, te recomiendo [leas el excelente aporte de @BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27459133)